# Gnome-terminal cannot send EOF after pasting huge amount of data

Tags: gnome-terminal

I am using gnome-terminal version 3.6.2. When I copy a sufficiently large amount of data (in my case, 86KB appears to be "sufficiently large") and then paste it into gnome-terminal, most of the data appears in the terminal, and then it appears I'm hitting some kind of buffer limit, as I can only see the rest of my pasted data in the terminal after hitting enter (or inputting additional data, or ^C, or whatever). My guess is that this buffer might be around 64KB in size, but I am probably totally wrong. Anyway, when I paste this much data into the terminal, there is a good chance (more than half the time) that *ALL* instances of gnome-terminal that I have open and any instances that I open after that point will no longer be able to send an EOF/Control-D. I can operate within gnome-terminal normally, except that I cannot send an EOF to the terminal using Control-D.

In a failed attempt to resolve my issue, I have reassigned "eof" to other character sequences, for example using: `stty eof ^J`

Power-cycling the entire machine does not fix the problem. I'm not sure yet what the catalyst is, but after some days, the issue resolves itself. However that is of course not an acceptable solution, to wait it out. What is happening? What else could I try?

Answer (score 0):

I found elsewhere a suggestion to run `stty sane` which as you might imagine resets to sane defaults. This solves my problem, but after taking a close look at what the differences could be, I'm still not sure exactly what about that particular command is fixing the problem. It works, though. Thanks for playing the rubber duck.